# .htaccess get lost query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have limited `.htaccess` knowledge and i am requiring some help. I need to do some redirects to enable pretty urls. 
In local all works fine but it is not working in another develpment server. apparently the query string get drop when redirect. 
i need to redirect this `http://mysite.local/info/permalink/1`

to this one `http://mysite.local/info?proxy=true&id=1`

**my `.htaccess` code:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#remove /index.php from home url and redirect to root.
#http://mysite.local/index.php -> http://mysite.local/ 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\/index\.php?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php?$ "/$1" [R=301,L,QSA]

#pretty url without index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [PT,QSA,L]

#rewrite to handle some permalink saved on my db.
#http://mysite.local/info/permalink/1
#http://mysite.local/info/proxy=true&id=1
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/info/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([0-9]+) /info/?proxy=true&id=$3 [L]
</IfModule>
```

the redirect is working but the query string is not present. When I run `var_dump($_GET)` on info module i am getting an empty array `array(0) {}` 
i have try it to solve changing

`RewriteRule .* index.php [PT,QSA,L]`

to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%{QUERY_STRING} [L]`

and

`RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/info/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([0-9]+) /info/?proxy=true&idobj=$3 [L]`

to

`RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/info/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([0-9]+) /info/?proxy=true&idobj=$3 [QSA,NE,L]`

Server API is CGI/FastCGI

What should I change to ensure that my rewrite works as intended and `$_GET` variables still are accessible?
thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea how you've managed to get this to work with a regex pattern like: `^([^/]+)/info` if the URL you are going to is `/info/permalink/1`.

The `^([^/]+)/info` pattern means there's stuff before the `/info` part of the URI, which there isn't. Additionally, in an htaccess file, the URI's have the leading forward slash stripped off. So you probably want something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^info/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([0-9]+) /info/?proxy=true&id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Thx about the answer. That i said, i have limited .htaccess knowledge. 
 In my local pc my htaccess works. If I use your modification it not works. but the problem not is my machine but the testing server. Anyway in the testing server your solution still not work.